# ES6 - Promise.all within a Promise.resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm using `ecmascript 6` and am trying to execute a `Promise.all()` within a `Promise.resolve()` together in my API.

Here's my code:

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import Database from "../../../util/Database";
import send from "../../../util/send";

var updatePosition = function(organizationId, positionId, positionTitle) {
  let updatedPosition = {
    organization_id: organizationId,
    title: positionTitle
  };
  return Database.connection.query('UPDATE positions SET ? WHERE id=?', [updatedPosition, positionId]);
}

var unLinkUserToPosition = function(positionId) {
  return Database.connection.query('UPDATE users SET position_id=NULL WHERE position_id=?', positionId);
}

var linkUserToPosition = function(positionId, userId) {
  return Database.connection.query('UPDATE users SET position_id=? WHERE id=?', [positionId, userId]);
}

var getPositionAndCommittees = function(positionId) {
  return Promise.all([getPosition(positionId), getCommittees(positionId)]).then(formatJSON);
}

var getPosition = function(positionId) {
  return Database.connection.query('SELECT \
    p.id as position_id, \
    p.title as position_title, \
    u.id as user_id, \
    u.facebook_UID, \
    u.email, \
    u.first_name, \
    u.last_name, \
    u.phone, \
    u.semester_joined, \
    u.year_joined, \
    u.thumbnail_photo_URL, \
    u.cover_photo_URL \
    FROM positions p \
    LEFT JOIN users u ON p.id=u.position_id \
    WHERE p.id=? \
    ORDER BY p.id ASC', positionId);
}

var getCommittees = function(positionId) {
  return Database.connection.query('SELECT \
    c.id as committee_id, \
    c.title as committee_title, \
    u.id as chairmen_user_id, \
    u.thumbnail_photo_URL as chairmen_thumbnail_photo_URL, \
    u.first_name as chairmen_user_first_name, \
    u.last_name as chairmen_user_last_name \
    FROM committees c \
    LEFT JOIN users u ON c.chairmen_id=u.id \
    WHERE c.position_id=? ORDER BY c.title ASC', positionId);
}

var formatJSON = function(results) {
  let positionResult = results[0][0];
  let committeesResult = results[1];
  let position = {
    id: positionResult.position_id,
    title: positionResult.position_title,
    user: {
      id: positionResult.user_id,
      facebookUID: positionResult.facebook_UID,
      email: positionResult.email,
      firstName: positionResult.first_name,
      lastName: positionResult.last_name,
      phone: positionResult.phone,
      semesterJoined: positionResult.semester_joined,
      yearJoined: positionResult.year_joined,
      thumbnailPhotoURL: positionResult.thumbnail_photo_URL,
      coverphotoURL: positionResult.cover_photo_URL
    },
    committees: committeesResult
  };

  return position;
}

module.exports = function(req, res) {
  let token = req.headers['bearer-authorization'];
  let tokenSecret = ENV.API_SECRET
  let decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, tokenSecret);

  let organizationId = 1
  let positionId = req.params.positionId;
  let positionTitle = req.body.title;
  let positionUserId = req.body.userId;

  Promise.resolve(updatePosition(organizationId, positionId, positionTitle))
    .then(unLinkUserToPosition(positionId))
    .then(linkUserToPosition(positionId, positionUserId))
    .then(getPositionAndCommittees(positionId))
    .then(send.success(res))
    .catch(send.failure(res));
};
```

---

Side Note: I'm using `promise-mysql` for my database queries, which means that when I return `Database.connection.query()`, it's actually returning a new Promise

---

Here's what the `send.success` and `send.failure` functions look like:

```
var send = {
  success: function(response) {
    return function(data) {
      response.status(200).json(data);
    };
  },
  failure: function(response) {
    return function(error) {
      var statusCode = error.statusCode || 500;

      if (statusCode === TEMPORARY_REDIRECT && error.body && error.body.value) {
          response.status(200).json(error.body.value);
          return;
      }

      console.error(error.stack);

      response.status(statusCode).json({
        message: error.message
      });
    };
  }
}
```

---

Heres the order I'm trying to get my functions to execute:

1. updatePosition
2. unLinkUserToPosition
3. linkUserToPosition
4. getPositionAndCommittees - This function calls Promise.all with `getPosition` and `getCommittees` and is supposed to call formatJSON as soon as getPosition() and getCommittees() finish executing and return the formatted JSON Data
5. send.success - This just outputs the JSON that should be returned from formatJSON

The way it's executing right now is that the data returned from `linkUserToPosition` is being returned as the data in the `send.success` function, which means that the `Promise.resolve` is not waiting for `getPositionAndCommittees` to finish executing the `Promise.all`.

Here's what the output looks like:

```
{
  "fieldCount": 0,
  "affectedRows": 1,
  "insertId": 0,
  "serverStatus": 2,
  "warningCount": 0,
  "message": "(Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0",
  "protocol41": true,
  "changedRows": 0
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish what I'm trying to do would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Side note: I think your `Promise.resolve` function is superfluos. As you are assigning a promise to it (the promise that .catch returns) it won't be resolved immediatly and it returns a promise too. And you actually ignore the promise, so you don't need it. You can simply start the async operation with `updatePosition(...)`.

Comment: @Matthias247 thanks for the tip! I updated it to start with `updatePosition()`. Still no luck on getting the send.success function to be called after the getPositionAndCommittees promise finishes though

Comment: Is formatJSON being called?

Comment: Based on the discussion on the deleted answer I think your code looks ok. The last idea that I have is: What does Database.connection.query() return? Is it a plain javascript object? Or might it be some kind of cursor whose instance is reused by the DB library? In that case you might need to clone the query results into a plain JSON object after each step. And does the DB actually support concurrenct queries?

Comment: Seems like parallel queries are not supported: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#executing-queries-in-parallel

Comment: @Matthias247 when I remove Promise.resolve, this message is being outputted in my console: `Warning: .then() only accepts functions but was passed: [object Object]`. Also, `formatJSON` is being called, but it's being called after `send.success`

Comment: And that's weird that parallel queries aren't supported because the data in formatJSON is correct. However, that could be the reason send.success is being called before getPositionAndCommittees promise finishes

Comment: Ah, now I got it. Will post a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that several functions are immediatly started and not only after the previous steps completed.

Assuming this call chain:

```
updatePosition(organizationId, positionId, positionTitle)
.then(unLinkUserToPosition(positionId))
.then(linkUserToPosition(positionId, positionUserId))
.then(getPositionAndCommittees(positionId))
.then(send.success(res))
.catch(send.failure(res));
```

This means the asynchronous functions `updatePosition`, `unLinkUserToPosition`, `linkUserToPosition` and `getPositionAndCommittees` will all be immediately started. The send functions too, but as these return a function which will be executed later it's no problem. This means the functions execute immediatley and the resulting promise is assigned to `.then()` of the previous function - which makes no sense because then accepts a function (that might return a promise), and not a promise. What you need is:

```
updatePosition(organizationId, positionId, positionTitle)
.then(updatePositionResult => unLinkUserToPosition(positionId))
.then(unLinkUserToPositionResult => linkUserToPosition(positionId, positionUserId))
.then(linkUserToPositionResult => getPositionAndCommittees(positionId))
.then(send.success(res))
.catch(send.failure(res));
```

Comment: Didn't even know I could do that! I'm gonna have to look up what this does `=>`, but you got it working! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.